# Adding picture library snippet to custom master page

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-masterpage, snippet

I have created a custom master page and i want to add picture library snippet to the page but i keep getting this error,note i done some research which keep saying to keep all URL field blank,in my case does not work[image]